# Convert 16-Bit RAW RGB_565 Image to Bitmap on Android

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, rgb

I am trying to get a 16-bit color image that is 80 x 60 resolution from an embedded camera ([datasheet here](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/451/uCAM-DS-rev7-3555.pdf)). I am successfully able to get 9600 (80 * 60 * 16 / 8) bytes from the camera, but I have a problem displaying the image. I am using the following code to convert the byte array into a Bitmap:

```
bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(80, 60, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
bm.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(jpegBytes));
```

jpegBytes is the array of the image's bytes and it is 9600 bytes long.

Right now, I am getting images that look like this:

[image: corrupted image]

99% of the time. However, I am able to get non-corrupted images that look like this:

[image: uncorrupted image]

very rarely.

It seems like all the pixels are in the correct spot, but have their RGB values mixed up. For example, the white portion between both photos is the same because the order of RGB does not matter to get white. However, it is clear that the colors are mixed up because the red chair is showing up as blue in the corrupted image and the blue backpack is showing up as green in the corrupted image.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this is happening?

Comment: 1) How are you getting your data - Section 4.3/4.4 - RAW or packaged. If you are using RAW have you tried packaged as RAW would be subject to noise problems. 2) Are you correctly accounting for big-endian/little-endian bytes or byte ordering in your receiver code.

Comment: I am getting my data RAW. I know the RAW data is not getting corrupted because when I get a video-feed from the camera using the computer software that came with it, I am able to get consistent, non-corrupted 16-bit color video. What do you mean "accounting for big/little-endian" byte ordering? I know for 4 and 8 bit video, I have to worry about byte ordering, but shouldn't Android's method take care of 16-bit byte ordering for me?

Comment: Didn't know that Android software came with it. My assumption was you were somehow getting the serial signal into Android and trying to get a bitmap from there. As a test, capture a single color image and look at the data to see if the RGB values aren't getting swapped. Since your pics have white still looking white but other colors are wrong, I would start there.